# Electron - Update window message

Tags: javascript, updates, electron, squirrel

I am using Squirrel for updates in my app(Electron).

And I'm looking for nice way to display release notes.
Something like this:
[image]

Where can I found information about this? 
How can I make my message window looks like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only ways to do that is :

- Create an HTML popup with that interface, clickable buttons... but you'll have to define all styles by yourself ;
- Else you'll have to make a C++ addon like a lot of projects, this addon will create the custom window when you ask, but that's complicated to do.

I know you can make custom dialog windows but less complex than this one with the `dialog.showMessageBox()` API ([See more here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options-callback))

Comment: Ok, I'm using simple dialog.showMessageBox... Will think about some HTML "popup" with designed release notes. Thank you!